# Alterar icon mylocation

Tags: java, android, xml

Criei um xml com uma ImageView informando a imagem que desejo colocar no lugar do icon.

Quero colocar essa imagem no lugar da bola azul da imagem a baixo.

> **É possível alterar o icon do mylocation ?
>   Se sim, qual é o processo ?**

Obrigado.

[image: mylocation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alterar este ícone não é possível, contudo você pode desabilitá-lo e inserir um marker customizado na mesma posição.

```
    googleMapObject.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.minha_imagem))
    );
```

Use de preferencialmente o `FusedLocationProvider` para saber a localização do usuário.

Comment: A sua resposta ficaria valorizada se explicasse como usar esse "marker customizado". Da forma como está parece mais um comentário do que uma resposta.

Comment: @ramaral feito!